# Imagick and Ligatures

Tags: php, gd, imagick

So I have a font with a bunch of ligatures in it. How would I go about getting Imagick to use those ligatures when converting text to an image.

For example "AB" is a special character as is "AC" and so forth.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like nobody cares. I would love a solution for this too.